# insmod not throwing error for a positive return

Tags: kernel-module, insmod

I am writing my first kernel module and it is a simple Hello World Kernel Module. The tldp guide I am following said that insmod would not load a module if the init_module function returns a non-zero value.
It is working as expected when returning some negative number but while experimenting I noticed that insmod is loading my module even when the return value is positive.

Please explain why?

For example if I return -185, insmod is straight away saying that it cannot load the module.

But when i return 185, it is informing about a suspicious return but still is loading the module.
This is the log for "return 185".

```
[19398.947857] do_init_module: 'hello_1'->init suspiciously returned 185, it should follow 0/-E convention
do_init_module: loading module anyway...
[19398.947859] CPU: 0 PID: 11812 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE  3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu
[19398.947860] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[19398.947861]  ffffffffc06c3000 ffff880059347d98 ffffffff817c2205 0000000000000007
[19398.947862]  ffffffffc06c3018 ffff880059347ee8 ffffffff810f9a2d ffffffff810f51d0
[19398.947864]  ffff8800db64ad10 ffff880059347e40 ffffffffc06c3018 ffffffffc0391000
[19398.947865] Call Trace:
[19398.947869]  [<ffffffff817c2205>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[19398.947872]  [<ffffffff810f9a2d>] load_module+0x160d/0x1ce0
[19398.947873]  [<ffffffff810f51d0>] ? store_uevent+0x40/0x40
[19398.947875]  [<ffffffff810fa276>] SyS_finit_module+0x86/0xb0
[19398.947877]  [<ffffffff817c934d>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

And this gets printed on console for "return -185"

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module hello-1.ko: Unknown error 185
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

init_module function *should* return either 0 or negative error code. You can treat returning positive value as leading to `undefined behaviour`.

Current kernel interprets positive value as `success`, but prints warning into system log. This log can be read using `dmesg`.